# Non-xml AttributeSet source

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm currently looking into a possible custom solution for the `AttributeSet`. Having made a wrapper for it, I got an error with the `java.lang.ClassCastException: AttributeSetWrapper cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser`.
Having searched a little on the Internet, I realized that somewhere in the android sources there is a cast to the private and final implementation of `AttributeSet` (kinda optimization).
How realistic is it somehow to add your attributes without xml in runtime? Taking into account the fact that Android Studio somehow renders all this.
I understand that this is not quite right from the point of view of Android, but I want to explore the possibilities of bypassing (somehow through reflection or other ways).

Comment: You've hit the same stopping point that many of us have previously. AFAIK, nobody's figured out a way around that.

Comment: so, it impossible at all?

Comment: Not as far as I know.